# Building PHP Admin Backend for pretty simple site

Tags: php, mysql, admin

I have taken over a website that is about 5 years old and the backend is pretty bad and a bit broken.

I would like to build a new backend "Quickly". I have PHP 5.3.4 and a mysql database.

There are 5 or so tables.

- Categories (eg, headphones, turntables)
- Products (they have a Category Foreign Key, eg to say what category this product belongs in).
- Products also an image field (path to image file), so image upload would be good.
- All the other tables a flat.

I would prefer not to hand code this system, I looked at building the backend in Symfony, that looks pretty awesome but looks like few days work.

Any suggestions other than PHP MyAdmin (please no...) to allow my client to admin is backend?

Thanks, John.

Comment: I think its clear, "what backend tools should I use" to make a pretty simple MySql table admin with PHP. Any experience's here?

Comment: what would be the main functions of the backend: inserting records, modifying them, adding new pages, analyzing stats, or else?

Comment: Hi Dennis, inserting, editing, deleting. No stats, no analyzing. Only 1 table has a FK from another table which would be nice if this is a drop down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caveats: most "application generation" software has a clichéd title and is aimed at novices.

- [dadabik](http://www.dadabik.org/) - Open Source, free but requests donation
- [ScriptArtist](http://www.scriptartist.com/livedemo.html) - highly customisable
- [SQLMaestro](http://www.sqlmaestro.com/products/mysql/phpgenerator/) - nice interface
- [AppGini](http://www.bigprof.com/appgini/) - feels clunky
- [PHPMyEdit](http://www.phpmyedit.org/) - Open Source, feels dated
- [City Business Logic](http://www.citybusinesslogic.com/) - website circa 1995